# Existing class/method for parsing fully qualified Type name

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

**Given** that I have a type "Wibble.Wobble" that exists in an assembly "Foo.Bar"

**And** that assembly is not loaded into the main applications load context

Is there an existing public mechanism for parsing the following string into its subsequent parts:

```
"Wibble.Wobble, Foo.Bar, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xyz"
```

The reason for asking is that I a need to load a variety of types at runtime, some of which may be in the current load context. Others may need to be loaded from an external assembly.

I know how to load types from the current load context `Type.GetType("typename")`, I know how to load an assembly and get a type from it `Assembly.LoadFile("xyz").GetType("abc")`. What I am having problems with is that if you try to load a type from an assembly **it should not be a fully qualified name** where as you can when using `Type.GetType`.

The solution itself should not be that complicated, it is just splitting the string before the first comma. However I wanted to know if there was a way of getting the fully qualified name as an object representation so I didn't have to do this and it would help with locating the right assembly without having to loop through a whole directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all my digging around I do not believe there is anything publicly available in the Framework that can do this. I would love for someone to show me different as I prefer to use core functionality that is (or should be) better tested and written by someone who has a better understanding of the framework than I do.

As such I have rolled my own strongly typed `TypeName` object.

```
class TypeName
{
    public TypeName(string name)
    {
        var index = name.LastIndexOf(',');
        if (index > 0)
        {
            Name = name.Substring(0, index).Trim();

            AssemblyName = new AssemblyName(name.Substring(index + 1).Trim());
        }
        else
        {
            Name = name;    
        }
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public AssemblyName AssemblyName { get; private set; }
}
```

The object takes in a `string` which should be either a type name or a fully qualified type name. If it is a fully qualified type name then the AssemblyName attribute is set using the AssemblyName class other wise it is left as null.

Comment: indexof gives you the first occurrence of a comma, which might be used as separator in generic arguments. That would not be pretty

Comment: @DavidSchmitt Fair point, I have not had to deal with that scenario yet but I have updated the example to use LastIndexOf instead of IndexOf. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: With LastIndexOf, it might just never work, consider
System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
last index of will just get the PublicKeyToken part

Comment: `typeof(IEquatable<IComparable<string>>).AssemblyQualifiedName` is a good test case...